# Calculate: $\iint_{D_1} e^{-2x^2 -4xy - 4y^2} \,dx\,dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Calculate:**

$$\iint_{D_1} e^{-2x^2 -4xy - 4y^2} \,dx\,dy$$

Where $D_1$ is the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

**Solution:**

We know that the integral:

$$\iint_\mathbb{R^2} e^{-u^2 -v^2} \,du\,dv = \pi$$

If we write:

$$-2x^2 -4xy - 4y^2 = -x^2 - (x+2y)^2$$

We get: 
$$u = x$$
$$v = x+2y$$

And: 
$$x = u$$
$$y = - \frac{u}{2} + \frac{v}{2} $$

The determinant for the transformation matrix will therefore be

$$\left|{1 \times \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \times 0} \right| = \frac{1}{2}$$

We then get:

$$\iint_{D_1} e^{-2x^2 -4xy - 4y^2} \,dx\,dy = \frac{1}{2}\iint_{D_2} e^{-u^2 -v^2} \,du\,dv$$

Now if ${D_2}$ would have been the same as $\mathbb{R^2}$ the answer would have been $\frac{1}{2}\pi$, the correct answer is $\frac{1}{16}\pi$.

Now one way to think about this is that the defined area is only the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and is hence only $\frac{1}{4}$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$... Still need some help to properly figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y\geq 0$, we have that $u\leq v$, hence your integral becomes 
\begin{align}
I&=\frac12\int_{u=0}^{\infty}\int_{v=u}^{\infty}e^{-u^2-v^2}dvdu\\
&=\frac12\times \frac{1}{8}\pi.
\end{align}